# Is there any way to search properly in array objects in Elasticsearch without changing to nested type?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch documents which has a field which is an array of objects. Eg.

```
"user" : [ 
    {
      "first" : "John",
      "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "last" :  "White"
    }
  ]
```

Now, there is a known issue that if we filter on these documents by say, first or last name inside user field, it doesn't give the correct results and which can be fixed if I make the `user` field as nested type:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

But making the field as nested requires deleting the old index and creating a new index, which looks like would require a downtime. So, I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any easy way to change the type to nested without deleting the index?
2. Is there any way to search correctly for this field without making the type as nested?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Simply add a new `nested` field the mapping:

```
PUT myindex/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "user_nested": {
      "type": "nested"
    }
  }
}
```

and then call `_update_by_query` with a script that sets the same content from the existing `user` to the new `user_nested` field:

```
POST myindex/_update_by_query?refresh
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.user_nested = ctx._source.user"
  }
}
```

Done.

2. No, there really is not.

Comment: did this help @hatellla?